# Pandas: how to keep data that has all the needed columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this big csv file that has data from an experiment. The first part of each person's response is a trial part that doesn't have the time they took for each response and I don't need that. After that part, the data adds another column which is the time, and those are the rows I need. So, basically, the csv has a lot of unusable data that has 9 columns instead of 10 and I need only the data with the 10 columns. How can I manage to grab that data instead of all of it?

As an example of it, the first row shows the data without the time column (second to last) and the second row the data I need with the time column added. I only need all the second rows basically, which is thousands of them. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,7,0,experimental-trial2,NULL,PennController,9,_Trial_,End,1619922289638,FLOR, red, r,NULL

1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,55,0,experimental-trial,NULL,PennController,56,_Trial_,Start,1619922296066,CASA, red, r,1230,NULL
```

Comment: You may want to try reducing your CSV in Python, then reading it in

Comment: Your csv has an header or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the CSV using pandas. Then filter by using `df[~df.time.isna()]` to select all rows with non NaN values in the "time" column.

You can change this to filter based on the presence of data in any column. Think of it as a mask (i.e. `mask = (~df.time.isna())` flags rows as True/False depending on the condition.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to load the whole file and then keep only valid data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")
invalid_rows = df.iloc[:,-1].isnull()  # Find rows, where last column is not valid (missing)
df = df[~invalid_rows]  # Select only valid rows
```

If you have columns named, then you can use `df['column_name']` instead of  `df.iloc[:,-1]`.

Of course it means you first load the full dataset, but in many cases this is not a problem.